# how would you extract last 3 characters from a string in a column of R dataframe?

Tags: r

WH-LKO

WH-CHE

WH-BLR

WH-BLR

WH-HYD

W1- GGN

WH12-GGN

WH3-GUW

F2-AMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `substring` with `nchar` to *extract last 3 characters from a string*.

```
substring(x, nchar(x)-2)
#[1] "LKO" "CHE"
```

Data:

```
x <- c("WH-LKO", "WH-CHE")
```